# Hidden div not being hidden on mobile

Tags: html, css

i'm using a bit of CSS to hide a div off-screen (and then jquery to animate it in) using this :

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hide {
    position: absolute !important;
    left:100vw !important;
}
```

On desktop, the div is being properly hidden, and no scrolbar appear, but on mobile, it is possible to scroll to the right and see this div.

Browsers not having the issue : Chrope/Edge/Firefox (All latest version as of today) on Win10
Browsers having the issue : Safari iOS (ios 9.x), Dolphin for android (latest) and firefox mobile (also latest)

See code here : https://jsfiddle.net/nfpwccvj/4/

Is there a way to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The first thing I see is the CSS for body is missing a closing-brace. is that a typo? Please also post your HTML and jquery.

Comment: Also need to know which browsers are involved, desktop and mobile.

Comment: See edited question for the browser list

Comment: Can't help you without html and jquery.

Comment: Right, sorry, here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/nfpwccvj/4/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the body `}`? Or it's just this example with this mistake?

Comment: Just a typo, my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

First of all `left:100vw` is not Cross-Browser supported, best practice for full width is `width:100%`. If you want to hide something on mobile, you need to use media query.

```
.hide {
    display:block;
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
   .hide {
       display:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to hide the div on mobile only, i'm trying to hide it everywhere, and the slide it in when i need to